# Process Builder : Global Picklist Value Fails

Tags: process-builder, global-picklist

Using  process builder and I try to set the value of a picklist field on a related object that is using global picklist functionality I get the error below.

> INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST: bad value for restricted picklist field: Individual/sole proprietor or single-member

It doesn't matter how I try to set the value of the field whether through reference field, formula, or even selecting the picklist value option it fails.

Comment: Please stop using the `[salesforce-crm]` tag. If you hover over it, the tag even says *This tag will be removed, do not use it.*

Comment: Check this link if you get any information : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kGGWIA2

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue and @sfdc rowdy's comment and [link above](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kGGWIA2) helped me fix it.

If you adjust/add a Global Picklist value, check each Record Type's picklist settings and make sure the adjusted/new values are selected.

Comment: This is especially annoying if (in my case) I'm working with Activity Record Types since this is sub divided into Task + Event record types... gotta check them *all*

Answer (score 0):

When creating these global picklists you have to go into the **recordtype** and edit the picklist and **assign** the picklist values to that record type.